# How to put fragmentbell post_id to acticvity android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

save sqlite database.bringing the saved data intent to the post id.Fragmentbell intent ActivityNotificationDetail not pass post_id sqlite to bell model class pass post id how to pass fragmentbell post_id how to slove this problem [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqVh4.png)

```
public class Fragmentbell extends Fragment {
LinearLayout linearLayout;
private View root_view;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
private Adapterbell adapterbell;
public static final String EXTRA_OBJC = "key.EXTRA_OBJC";
DbHandler databaseHandler;

` private ArrayList<bell> mNotificationList;

private ShimmerFrameLayout lyt_shimmer;
SharedPref sharedPref;
private List<bell> data = new ArrayList<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bell, container, false);


    
    loadDataFromDatabase();

    recyclerView = root_view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new EqualSpacingItemDecoration(0));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    adapterbell = new Adapterbell(getActivity(), recyclerView,data);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterbell);

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    adapterbell.setOnItemClickListener((v, obj, position) -> {

        databaseHandler = new DbHandler(getActivity());

        databaseHandler.updateStatus(data.get(position).getId(), true);


        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showInterstitialAd();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityNotificationDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", data.get(position).getpost_id());

      this.startActivity(intent);


    });


    return root_view;
}

private void loadDataFromDatabase() {
    databaseHandler = new DbHandler(getActivity());
    data = databaseHandler.getAllbell();

}
```

bell model class

```
`public class Adapterbell extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

private List<bell> items;

private boolean loading;
private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

private Context context;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
boolean scrolling = false;

private SharedPref sharedPref;



public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, bell obj, int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}

public Adapterbell(Context context, RecyclerView view, List<bell> items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
    this.sharedPref = new SharedPref(context);
    lastItemViewDetector(view);
}

public class OriginalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView category_name;
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView image;
    public ImageView thumbnail_video;
    public MaterialRippleLayout lyt_parent;

    public OriginalViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        category_name = v.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        title = v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_title);
        image = v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_image);
        thumbnail_video = v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_video);
        lyt_parent = v.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);
    }

}

public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        progressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.load_more);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
    if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_home_recipe, parent, false);
        vh = new OriginalViewHolder(v);
    } else {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_load_more, parent, false);
        vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
    }
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder instanceof OriginalViewHolder) {
        final bell b = items.get(position);

        final OriginalViewHolder vItem = (OriginalViewHolder) holder;


        vItem.title.setText(b.title);

        if (b.content_type != null && b.content_type.equals("youtube")) {
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(Constant.YOUTUBE_IMAGE_FRONT + b.video_id + Constant.YOUTUBE_IMAGE_BACK_MQ)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
                    .into(vItem.image);
        } else {
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(sharedPref.getApiUrl() + "/upload/" + b.image)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
                    .into(vItem.image);
        }

        if (b.content_type != null && b.content_type.equals("Post")) {
            vItem.thumbnail_video.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            vItem.thumbnail_video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        vItem.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, b, position);
            }
        });

    } else {
        ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_PROG) {
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
    } else {
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(false);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (items.get(position) != null) {
        return VIEW_ITEM;
    } else {
        return VIEW_PROG;
    }
}

public void insertData(List<bell> items) {
    setLoaded();
    int positionStart = getItemCount();
    int itemCount = items.size();
    this.items.addAll(items);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
}

public void setLoaded() {
    loading = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i) == null) {
            items.remove(i);
            notifyItemRemoved(i);
        }
    }
}

public void setLoading() {
    if (getItemCount() != 0) {
        this.items.add(null);
        notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
        loading = true;
    }
}

public void resetListData() {
    this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
    this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
}

private void lastItemViewDetector(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
        final StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int lastPos = getLastVisibleItem(layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPositions(null));
                if (!loading && lastPos == getItemCount() - 1 && onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                    int current_page = getItemCount() / AppConfig.POST_PER_PAGE;
                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore(current_page);
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
    void onLoadMore(int current_page);
}

private int getLastVisibleItem(int[] into) {
    int last_idx = into[0];
    for (int i : into) {
        if (last_idx < i) last_idx = i;
    }
    return last_idx;
}

}
```

``
bell

```
public class bell implements Serializable {

    public int id;

    public String unique_id;
    public String title;
    public String message;
    private boolean isUnread;
    public String big_image;

    public String image;

    public String content_type;

    public String video_id;

    public String link;

    public String post_id;

    public bell( String title, String message, String big_image, String image, String content_type, String video_id, String link,String post_id, boolean isUnread) {
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
        this.big_image = big_image;
        this.image = image;
        this.content_type = content_type;
        this.video_id = video_id;
        this.link = link;
        this.post_id = post_id;
        this.isUnread = isUnread;


    }

    public bell() {

    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public String getunique_id() {
        return unique_id;
    }

    public void setunique_id(String unique_id) {
        this.unique_id = unique_id;
    }



    public String gettitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void settitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getmessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setmessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }



    public String getbig_image() {
        return big_image;
    }

    public void setbig_image(String big_image) {
        this.big_image = big_image;
    }


    public String getimage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setimage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getcontent_type() {
        return content_type;
    }


    public String getvideo_id() {
        return video_id;
    }

    public void setvideo_id(String video_id) {
        this.video_id = video_id;
    }
    public void setcontent_type(String content_type) {
        this.content_type = content_type;
    }


    public String getpost_id() {
        return post_id;
    }

    public void setpost_id(String post_id) {
        this.post_id = post_id;
    }

    public boolean isUnread() {
        return isUnread;
    }
```

How to get arraylist sqlite to fragment android

Comment: @Yunnosch   update  code check bro

Comment: @Yunnosch how to put post_id fragmentbell to ActivityNotificationDetail class

Comment: @Yunnosch  HI I AM new android devloper fragment to activity how to post_id pass

Comment: @Yunnosch  update code   intent.putExtra("id", data.get(position).getpost_id());  how to pass post id

Comment: @Yunnosch  data get sqlite database post id https://postimg.cc/wRgm80Hx

Comment: Never mind, but being a non-native speaker myself I do need the additional help to understand posts which is provided by full sentences. It is OK if you cannot do that. I just cannot even start to try and help you with the fragmented collection of words and code which I perceive your post to be. Good luck.